# HTML,CSS - show two photos on top of each other while sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I am a beginner and I do not know how to ask the question correctly, but I hope you can help me.

I want to superimpose two photos and then put a point in the middle that you can drag left and right to display one or the other photo.

This would allow you to show a before and after comparison for example.

My question: Is this possible with HTML + CSS? Or do you need JS?
I ask for solution suggestions.

Comment: You need JS for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO - please read this on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You will need JS since you have to implement the dragging (which will change the width of the top image).

Comment: `https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp` are you talking about this?

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.